# pom.xml not found in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a question for Jenkins .I have a pipeline and I am trying to execute following script

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven "maven-3.6"}
    stages {

        stage('Increment Version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'incrementing app version...'
                    sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
                        -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} \
                        versions:commit'
                    def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+)</version>'
                    def version = matcher[0][1]
                    env.IMAGE_NAME = "$version-$BUILD_NUMBER"
                            }
            }
        }
        stage('Build App') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo 'Building the Application'
                    sh "mvn package"
                    }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploying Step') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploy the App'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, I am failing with the following error

[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/DEMO_INCREMENT_APP_VERSION_JOB). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

I have the following files in my Jenkins workspace and my directory is **java-maven-app-master-increment** like below

jenkins@eddbe362cee4:~/workspace/DEMO_INCREMENT_APP_VERSION_JOB$ ls -la
total 24388

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1637 Jun 22 11:32  DeviceList_91.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1618 Jun 22 11:32  DeviceList_98.xml
drwxr-xr-x  4 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 11:32  FlaskMarket
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 11:32  Flask_app
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins    65422 Jun 22 11:32  GitWorkflow1.png
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      512 Jun 22 11:32  Jenkinsfile
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      879 Jun 22 11:32  Jenkinsfile6
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       49 Jun 22 11:32  README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1121 Jun 22 11:32  collect_endpoint.py
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 11:32  developing-with-docker-master
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins        0 Jun 22 11:32  docker_file_example.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1488 Jun 22 11:32  dockercommands.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      516 Jun 22 11:32  factorial.py
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      572 Jun 22 11:32  fibonaci.py
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       14 Jun 22 11:32  freestyle-build.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1407 Jun 22 11:32  gitcommands.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1964 Jun 22 11:32  interface_policies.xml
drwxr-xr-x  5 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 11:32  java-app-master
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 15:17  java-maven-app-master-increment
```

I tried to change the directory with sh "cd java-maven-app-master-increment" but it did not help

Comment: So as the error message tells there is no `pom.xml` in the given directory... I would recommend to take a look into `java-maven-app-master-increment` ...

Comment: yeah, I totally understand, but as you see in the below command it is there actually

```jenkins@eddbe362cee4:/$ ls -la /var/jenkins_home/workspace/DEMO_INCREMENT_APP_VERSION_JOB/java-maven-app-master-increment/
total 36
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   14 Jun 22 13:34 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 1185 Jun 22 15:17 Jenkinsfile
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 3474 Jun 22 13:56 pom.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  532 Jun 22 13:34 script.groovy
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 22 13:34 src```

Comment: The question is simply why do you have that sub directory and why is the pom file incl. the src directory not one level higher... also the question is coming up what the directory `java-app-maven` is related to? Furthermore in the Jenkins pipline there is a thing called `readPom(..)` instead of `def matcher = readFile(..`....